# Not initially displaying all comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, display

There is an annoying feature of the comments which I would like to see changed.

When there are many comments on a question/answer, only a few of the comments are initially shown, and one needs to click underneath to display more comments. This feature is understandable and logical if only the first few chronologically made comments are displayed, but the system does not do that. Instead, many times it will display e.g. four comments, but not the first four but displays e.g. the first comment, skip one, display the third, skip two, and so on.

The problem is that the comments many times are a dialogue between two or more people, and if comments are skipped the displayed comments make no sense. My first thought when I have encountered such cases is that one person erased their comments, and only after scrolling down the page do I see that there are more comments available, and that they fill in the gaps in the dialogue.

Would it be possible to change this feature to display the first few comments without skipping?

Comment: It only skips when it boosts highly voted comments up. Generally, comments with upvotes are more valuable and more helpful to be seen.

Comment: @AA -Yes, I realized that this how it works, my point is many posts have dialogues in the comments, so initially displaying only the upvoted questions creates weird situations.

Answer (score 3):

Note that comments are not meant to include dialogue. Please see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment (the entire page is worth a read). So the reason you give for your feature request is one that doesn't match the way the site is meant to work.

Comment: Yes, אבל למעשה...